gdaldem hillshade leaves holes in map at hill shadows
I have followed the install guide for OpenTopoMap exactly, this can be found here: https://github.com/der-stefan/OpenTopoMap/blob/master/mapnik/README.md#compile-and-install-mod_tile
When I view the map it shows me blocks, which looks to be to be the darkest points of the shadows.
So maybe missing data?
Here is an example of this hillshading:

I have tried multiple data sources, even the included SRTM in this build example and I get these results every time. So my conclusion is I am doing something wrong when importing this detail. Below is my generation code of the hill shading and of the contour lines before importing to the database:
#!/bin/bash


cd /mnt

if [ ! -d "/mnt/srtm" ]; then
  echo "Please put some HGT ZIP files into the directory /mnt/data/srtm."
  exit
fi

mkdir /data/srtm

cd /mnt/srtm

for zipfile in *.zip; do unzip -j -o "$zipfile" -d /data/srtm; done

echo "Fill all the Voids"
cd /data/srtm
for hgtfile in *.hgt; do gdal_fillnodata.py $hgtfile $hgtfile.tif; done
echo "Fill all the voids complete!"

echo "Merge all tifs"
#gdal_merge.py -n 32767 -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -o ../raw.tif *.hgt.tif
gdal_merge.py -n 32767 -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -o /data/srtm/raw.tif *.hgt.tif
echo "Merge all tifs complete"

echo "Convert the raw file into Mercator projection, interpolate and shrink"
cd /data/srtm
gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 1000 1000 raw.tif warp-1000.tif
gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 5000 5000 raw.tif warp-5000.tif
gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 500 500 raw.tif warp-500.tif
# 60m - just for contour lines
gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 700 700 raw.tif warp-700.tif
# 30m - for the detail hillshade
gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 90 90 raw.tif warp-90.tif
echo "Convert the raw file into Mercator projection, interpolate and shrink complete!"

echo "Create color relief for different zoom level"
# relief for zoom factors 1-4
gdaldem color-relief -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -alpha warp-5000.tif /data/OpenTopoMap/mapnik/relief_color_text_file.txt relief-5000.tif
# relief for zoom factors 5-8
gdaldem color-relief -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -alpha warp-500.tif /data/OpenTopoMap/mapnik/relief_color_text_file.txt relief-500.tif
echo "Create color relief for different zoom level complete"

# create hillshade
echo "Create hillshade for different zoom levels"
gdaldem hillshade -z 7 -compute_edges -co COMPRESS=LZW warp-5000.tif hillshade-5000.tif
gdaldem hillshade -z 7 -compute_edges -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW warp-1000.tif hillshade-1000.tif
gdaldem hillshade -z 4 -compute_edges -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW warp-700.tif hillshade-700.tif
gdaldem hillshade -z 2 -co compress=lzw -co predictor=2 -co bigtiff=yes -compute_edges warp-90.tif hillshade-90.tif && gdal_translate -co compress=LZW -co bigtiff=yes -co tiled=yes hillshade-90.tif hillshade-90-jpeg.tif
echo "Create hillshade for different zoom levels complete"

echo "Create contour lines"
pyhgtmap -o contour --max-nodes-per-tile=0 -s 10 --jobs 12 -0 --pbf warp-90.tif
echo "Create contour lines complete"

mv *.osm.pbf contours.pbf

There was a thread logged against the project (https://github.com/der-stefan/OpenTopoMap/issues/337) and I have tried different methods to try make it work without success.
It seems there is missing data?
Anyone with an idea of how I could try make this work?

I fixed the same issue by writing here: OpenTopoMap/mapnik/styles-otm
/hillshade.xml

    hillshade-90
    
        gdal
        dem/hillshade-90.tif
        tiff
    


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
